# Refactor package name in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to rename the package name inside my project for android studio. Before, it was `com.example.chris` but I am trying to rename and reference the new package name: `release.com.build`. I went inside my AndroidManifest.xml and refactored the old package but the problem is it is still referencing my old package name when I attempt to run the simulator even though I am sure it does not exist.

Can anyone give me a suggestion on how to rename correctly? I must be missing something?

```
 Launching application: release.com.build/com.example.chris.MainActivity.
 DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start  -n "release.com.build/com.example.chris.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
 Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=release.com.build/com.example.chris.MainActivity }
 Error type 3
 Error: Activity class {release.com.build/com.example.chris.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have package name in all the classes ,Build level gradle, and the project folders will be created according to your package name try renaming all of these ..

Comment: I don't see the old reference in my project folders. Where specifically? I even checked the build.gradles